# Why does this code work on PHP Version 5.2.10 and not on PHP Version 5.2.10-2?

Tags: php, ubuntu, versioning, wamp

With this code I am iterating trough an object. Why is this working on my WAMP box with PHP 5.2.10 and isn't it on my Ubuntu 9.10 installation with PHP 5.2.10-2 from the repo's?

```
$incomingData = json_decode($_POST['data']);

foreach($incomingData as $key => $action)
{

}
```

> Invalid argument supplied for
>   foreach()

Comment: I'm guessing this has got something to do with the json_decode part, but I'm also guessing you might want to ask this on Stack Overflow instead of here.

Answer (score 3):

wzzrd is correct. This should likely be on stackoverflow, and the issue will be with the return value from json_decode not being what you expected.

From http://php.net/json_decode

> Returns the value encoded in json in
>   appropriate PHP type. Values true,
>   false and null (case-insensitive) are
>   returned as TRUE, FALSE and NULL
>   respectively. NULL is returned if the
>   json cannot be decoded or if the
>   encoded data is deeper than the
>   recursion limit.

Are you making the same request on both servers (&data=xxx is exactly the same)? That'd be the first thing to verify.

Assuming yes, are your php.ini's similar?

`magic_quotes_gpc=1` will alter $_GET/$_POST/$_COOKIE and is the likely culprit.